# gRPC Kotlin / Java performance difference

Tags: java, kotlin, grpc, grpc-java

I've implemented a simple gRPC demo project using Kotlin. The demo flow consists of several parts: preforming two requests, many subsequent ones to warm up and the last request. I have implemented the same demo in Java to compare the performance.
The full code can be found here: https://github.com/Frame17/grpc-demo .
The proto definitions:

```
syntax = "proto3";
option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "application";

package grpc;

message Request {
  string name = 1;
}

message Response {
  string message = 1;
}

service PingService {
  rpc Ping (Request) returns (Response) {}
}
```

The client code looks like this:

```
class TestClient(private val channel: ManagedChannel) {
    private val stub: PingServiceGrpcKt.PingServiceCoroutineStub = PingServiceGrpcKt.PingServiceCoroutineStub(channel)

    suspend fun ping() {
        val request = Request.newBuilder().build()
        stub.ping(request)
    }
}

fun main() {
    val port = 8080
    val channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", port).usePlaintext().build()
    val client = TestClient(channel)

    measureNanoTime {
        runBlocking {
            client.ping()
        }
    }.also {
        println("Connecting: $it")
    }

    measureNanoTime {
        runBlocking {
            client.ping()
        }
    }.also {
        println("Before warm up: $it")
    }

    val n = 100_000
    measureNanoTime {
        runBlocking {
            IntRange(0, n).map {
                async {
                    client.ping()
                }
            }.awaitAll()
        }
    }.also {
        println("Warm up: ${it / n}")
    }

    measureNanoTime {
        runBlocking {
            client.ping()
        }
    }.also {
        println("After warm up: $it")
    }
}
```

I get the following measurements(in nanoseconds) :

```
Connecting: 5923889409
Before warm up: 14580037
Warm up: 259311
After warm up: 20627192
```

There is a couple of things concerning me about it's performance:

- First request usually takes around 5 seconds. I'm assuming, it establishes an actual connection and the subsequent requests are reusing it. Can something be done to improve this?
- The request after warm up may take up to 20 milliseconds. The measurements of Java client are significantly different:

```
Connection: 5560394651
Before warm up: 6416257
Warm up: 358423
After warm up: 307845
```

The request after warm up takes no more than 0.5 milliseconds. Is there any issue in the code or what is the reason to it and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Can you please trying to send a request to your server-side via BloomRPC? And check to response.

Comment: @HalilSahin I see different timings here. First request takes around 300-400 milliseconds and the subsequent ones take 20-30 milliseconds to complete.

Comment: So, then i can tell you with my honest its maybe a bug of SDK.

Comment: @HalilSahin the problem with warm up requests and subsequent one timing does not look related to the SDK. It's that the same function completes in significantly different timings.

Comment: Your code makes no sense to me. You use a blocking stub but then launch a coroutine for each client call. There’s a dedicated project for [gRPC Kotlin](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-kotlin), as well as other implementations of gRPC in Kotlin. Also see https://grpc.io/blog/optimizing-grpc-part-1/

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar the blocking stub is used only for Java client, Kotlin uses `PingServiceGrpcKt.PingServiceCoroutineStub`. Same thing is done in the official [example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-kotlin/blob/master/examples/client/src/main/kotlin/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/HelloWorldClient.kt)

Comment: The official example isn’t meant for performance comparison.